# CoderByte Python import statements

Tags: python

I have been trying to import modules on my python Coderbyte challenges, but to no avail. I noticed that the C++ challenges allow includes, so I've been relying on ,  for the C++ challenges.

My question is, is there a way to successfully use other modules for challenges written in Python on Coderbyte?

Comment: In programming competition usually few selected libraries are allowed to be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coderbyte only has the standard 2.7.2 python. There is not a way to import a package they do not have setup for you to use in their environment.